# .animate infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am interested in a solution for jQuery `.animate` infinite loop break method.

```js
$(element).mouseover(function() {
   $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, duration, customFunc);
}).mouseout(function() {

});
```

And question now is how to break this loop? e.g within a `mouseout` event?

I can do it easily with `setInterval` and `clearInterval` but is there a way to it with **`.animate`** function?

Comment: I don't see an infinite loop (or any loop at all) in your code. Could you explain in more detail what you are trying to do?

Comment: You can, regardless of any other options, simply call `clearInterval` in the `mouseout` event.

Comment: I agree with nnnnnn, where is the infinite loop, unless this code is inside one?

Comment: The infinite loop is probably in customFunc, customFunc is the callback for after the animation ends that probably reinvokes the animation

Answer (score 4):

Use the .stop method:

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

I assume you want to immediately stop the currently running animation?

```
$(element).mouseover(function() {
   $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, duration, customFunc);
}).mouseout(function() {
   $(this).stop();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could stop the animation using .stop()

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

You might want to use .stop(true, true) to clear the queue and jump to the end of the animation

You can use .data() to store a flag of if you should animate anymore

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Add an IF in your customFunc before you invoke animate again to check the flag of whether or not you should animate.  That way you won't refire due to any other callbacks.  In your mouseover you should set the flag to be enabled again.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are experiencing is an effect where the animation queues up as your mouse enters and leaves the element repeatedly and continues to repeat the animation over and over several times after your mouse has left the element and not returned - I would recommend the jquery hoverflow plugin for you.

http://www.2meter3.de/code/hoverFlow/